# How to insert TODO comment in React JSX file

Tags: phpstorm, jsx, todo

I would like to insert TODO comments on a React JSX file, a regular JavaScript comments are parsed as text and rendered in my component PhpStorm list them in in TODO tool window

```
// TODO any comments ... 
or 
/* TODO an other todo task*/
```

in case when I use a JSX comment like this

```
{/* TODO an other todo task*/}
```

PhpStorm ignore the TODO and consider it as simple comment,  there is  a way to insert a TODO  with PhpStorm in React JSX file or there is a lack in PhpStorm support for react and it's requires an enhancement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks similar to [WEB-23401](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23401), please follow it for updates

Answer (score 0):

```
use the below comment it worked for me writing todo's
/**
   @todo: right your todo comment here
**/
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I'm gonna chime in for future visitors.

This worked for me:

```
{/* //TODO blablabla */}
```

It's a bit weird (you'll see for yourself), but it highlights as a TODO, throws no errors and is picked up by TODO indexing tools